# ggplot in BBC style: line and text under graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am following BBC style that is described [here](https://bbc.github.io/rcookbook/). However, cannot achieve a line and a text under graph that can be seen below. Would like to add the line and the `Source: Office for National Statistics`. How would you achieve that?

[image]

Comment: You can add a caption using labs() then left-adjust with theme(): e.g. `ggplot(data) + labs(caption = "Source: Office for National Statistics") + theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))`. If you want the entire theme, look at: https://github.com/bbc/bbplot

Comment: @jared_mamrot that worked like a charm! thank you! any idea how to include the horizontal line, though?

Comment: @bajun65537 You can check the `BBC` style package that `ggplot2` has. Here: https://github.com/bbc/bbplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BBC theme can be used per [github.com/bbc/bbplot](https://github.com/bbc/bbplot), but if you only want a caption and a line you can use grid/gridExtra, e.g.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

my_plot <- ggplot(data) +
           geom_xx

my_caption <- grobTree(linesGrob(unit(c(0, 1), "npc"), unit(1, "npc")),
                    textGrob("Caption goes here", x=0, hjust=0))

#Combine the plot and the caption/line
allplot <- grid.arrange(my_plot,my_caption,heights=c(1,0.05))
grid.draw(allplot)
```